# Personal information dataset

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am looking for a dummy dataset of personal data with these fields:

```
Name
Gender
Location
Age
```

Does anyone know where I could find something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used an [online tool](http://www.convertcsv.com/generate-test-data.htm) for this task. With this you can make dummy CSV, Excel, JSON and other files. You can choose the field names and types, and set limits and functions. 1000 rows are exportable per CSV. Here's a simple example - there are other websites that will do the same (e.g. [Mockaroo](https://www.mockaroo.com/))

[image]

Comment: Thanks  !! I think there is no other way than this. Thanks again !!